# Filters iTunes App Customer Reviews - Web service

Tags: php, ios

**Objective:**

To get customer reviews of app from iTunes and filters like Most Helpful, Most Recent on reviews.

**Supported Method By Apple:**

Apple provides an "App Reviews" web service to get customer reviews per app.

`API: http://itunes.apple.com/rss/customerreviews/id=400274934/xml`

**Problem:**

This web service provides all customer reviews on a particular AppID, but I want reviews which are Most Helpful or Most Recent, the way iTunes provides.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I web-searched to see if results for a particular app could be presented in a different order. I couldn't find that they could, so imagine you should download this programmatically:

http://itunes.apple.com/rss/customerreviews/id=400274934/sortby=mostrecent/page=1/xml

From there, download `/feed/link[@rel="last"]` using XPath in your XML reader. Parse out the page number, which appears to be one more than the last page. In this case, the last page is 13, so you should read pages 1 through to 12 and insert the data into a database. You can then apply your own sort as you see fit.

I noticed that 'xml' can be replaced with 'json' if that's easier for you to consume.

An easier solution may be available if you can find other valid values for 'sortby', but my guessing others (like 'rating') returned an empty document.

---

Hmm, a re-read of your question makes me think you just want votes for all applications. If so, you can generate a custom RSS feed here:

http://itunes.apple.com/rss/customerreviews/

Comment: Thanks!! you saved my life... i wanted to sort reviews by most recent or most helpful

Comment: No problem, glad that's sorted it for you.